# AWK searching records in one file for entries in another file

Tags: arrays, awk, full-text-search

I have a results.csv file that contains names in the following layout:

```
name1, 2(random number)  
name5, 3
```

and a sample.txt, that is structured in the following

```
record_seperator
name1
foo
bar
record_seperator
name2
bla
bluh
```

I would like to seach for each name in results.csv in the sample.txt file and if it is found output the record into a file.
I tried to generate an array out of the first file and search for that, but I couldn't get the syntax right. 
It needs to run in a bash script. If anyone has a better idea than awk, that is also good, but I do not have admin rights on the machine it is supposed to run. 
The true csv file contains 10.000 names and the sample.txt 4.5 million records.
I am a bloody beginner in awk, so explanation would be much appreciated. 
This is my current try, which does not work and I don't know why:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{
while (getline < "results.csv")
{
split($0,name,",");
nameArr[k]=name[1];
}
{
RS="record_seperator"
FS="\n"
for (key in nameArr)
        {
         print nameArr[key]
         print $2
         if ($2==nameArr[key])
                 NR > 1
                 {
                #extract file by Record separator and name from line2
                print RS $0 > $2 ".txt"
                }
        }
}
}' sample.txt
```

edit: 
my expected output would be two files:

name1.txt

```
record_seperator
name1
foo
bar
```

name2.txt

```
record_seperator
name2
bla
bluh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one. <s>As there was no expected output, it just outputs raw records</s>:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {              # process first file 
    a[$1]=RS $0        # hash the whole record with first field (name) as key 
    next               # process next record in the first file
}                      # after this line second file processing
$1 in a {              # if first field value (name) is found in hash a
    f=$1 ".txt"        # generate filename
    print a[$1] > f    # output the whole record
    close(f)           # preserving fds
}' RS="record_seperator\n" sample RS="\n" FS="," results  # file order and related vars
```

Only one match:

```
$ cat name1.txt
record_seperator
name1
foo
bar
```

Tested on gawk and mawk, acts weird on original-awk.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have to admid, I do not fully understand it. I added the expected output in my original post.

Comment: the result should contain the RS line "record_seperator"

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! Sorry for getting back so late. I had the flu and then a ton of work piled up.

Answer (score 0):

something like this, (*not tested*)

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next}                  # fill array with names from first file
           $1 in a {print rt, $0 > ($1".txt")}    # print the record from second file
                   {rt = RT}' results.csv RS="define_it_here" sample.txt
```

since your record separator is before the records, you need to delay it by one.

Use the build in line/record iterator instead of working it around.

Answer (score 0):

(Following @Tiw's lead, I also changed name5 to name2 in your results file in order to get the expected output)

```
$ cat a.awk
# collect the result names into an array
NR == FNR {a[$1]; next}

# skip the first (empty) sample record caused by initial record separator
FNR ==  1 { next }

# If found, output sample record into the appropriate file
$1 in a {
    f =  ($1 ".txt")
    printf "record_seperator\n%s", $0  > f
}
```

Run with gawk for multi-character RS:

```
$ gawk -f a.awk FS="," results.csv FS="\n" RS="record_seperator\n" sample.txt
```

Check results:

```
$ cat name1.txt
record_seperator
name1
foo
bar
$ cat name2.txt
record_seperator
name2
bla
bluh
```

Answer (score 0):

You code's errors:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{
while (getline < "results.csv")
{
split($0,name,",");
nameArr[k]=name[1];  ## <-- k not exists, you are rewriting nameArr[""] again and again.
}
{
RS="record_seperator"
FS="\n"
for (key in nameArr) ## <-- only one key "" exists, it's never gonna equal to $2
        {
         print nameArr[key]  
         print $2
         if ($2==nameArr[key])
                 NR > 1
                 {
                #extract file by Record separator and name from line2
                print RS $0 > $2 ".txt"
                }
        }
}
}' sample.txt
```

Also the sample you showed:

```
name1, 2(random number)  
name5, 3  ## <-- name5 here, not name2 !
```

Changed `name5` to `name2`, and with your own code updated:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{
    while ( (getline line< "results.csv") > 0 ) {  # Avoid infinite loop when read erorr encountered.
        split(line,name,",");
        nameArr[name[1]]; # Actually no need do anything, just refer once to establish the key (name[1]).
    }
    RS="record_seperator";
    FS="\n";
}

$2 in nameArr {
        print RS $0;  #You can add `> $2 ".txt"` later yourself.
}' sample.txt
```

Output:

```
record_seperator 
name1            
foo              
bar              

record_seperator 
name2            
bla              
bluh
```